# Newtonsoft JSON Deserialize Dynamically

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

Example JSON data:

```
{"t":"1339886","a":true,"data":[],"Type":[['Ants','Biz','Tro']]}
```

I found the Newtonsoft JSON.NET deserialize library for C#. 
If I use:

```
object JsonDe = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Json);
```

How can I access to the JsonDe object to get all the "Type" Data without creating a class?

The provided JSON is only an example, I have to manage a large JSON response from website an creating a class would be hard work.

Comment: Creating a class for JSON is *not* hard work -  you can paste the JSOn into Visual Studio and it will create the class(es) for you.

Comment: you can covert it into Dictionary<string,object>

Comment: You can use `JToken.Parse()` or `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(Json)` to parse JSON with no fixed schema.  See: [JObject.Parse vs JsonConvert.DeserializeObject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24645588).

Comment: Incidentally, you don't need to create a class for the *entire* data.  You could just create classes with the require data.  The rest will be ignored.

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp How can I do that?

Comment: Creating class file for JSON (no matter how large) is not that hard. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53119308/why-are-the-paste-json-as-classes-and-paste-xml-as-classes-commands-disabled

Comment: @NeDark - see [How to auto-generate a C# class file from a JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21611674/3744182).

Comment: I think class is definetly the best way to go. and as @dbc said "You could just create classes with the required data." meaning you could just create a class with your "Type" property otherwise you could try from the Newtonsoft.Json.Linq namespace `dynamic d = JObject.Parse({"t":"1339886","a":true,"data":[],"Type":[['Ants','Biz','Tro']]});` and use it like `d.Type`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked into using JsonLinq and `JObject.Parse()`?  You can then using something like the following:

```
string Data = "{\"t\":\"1339886\",\"a\":true,\"data\":[],\"Type\":[['Ants','Biz','Tro']]}";
JObject J = JObject.Parse(Data);
string[] Types = J["Type"][0].ToObject<string[]>();
```

Note: I didn't test this against your data structure.